# tailwindcss ring-offset has an artifact

Tags: tailwind-css

I get a weird artifact when using a border-radius and ring-offset on a button. You can see in the image there's a small artifact on the corner. Is there any way to fix this?

[image: button with artifact]

```
<button type="button" class="flex items-center rounded-md text-xs text-gray-500 underline outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-4">preview email</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the button a background color and it'll go away:

```
<button type="button" class="bg-white flex items-center rounded-md text-xs text-gray-500 underline outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-4">preview email</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this part make this: " focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-4 "

try:
Click Me

py and px (give your values)

or just add background color (( bg-white (or what you need) ))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that increases the size of the button when it's focused. I want to use `ring` because it's a box shadow and doesn't increase the size.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).